# Iterating over an Array and an Iterable (List)

Tags: java

I have a `byte` array and a `List` of a custom object `ByteRule` and I'm needing to loop around and perform an operation on both but only as long as one of both is available, the original method is as follows:

```
private final List<ByteRule> rules;

@Override
public boolean match(final InetAddress addr)
{
    final byte[] bytes = addr.getAddress();
    for(int i = 0; i < this.rules.size() && i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
        final int value = bytes[i] < 0 ? (int) bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
        if(!this.rules.get(i).match(value))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Obviously the `this.rules.get(i)` on every iteration is inefficient, however as I need to maintain a counter, an enhanced `for` loop means keeping a separate counter and performing a check on it every time like so (list declaration skipped for space):

```
@Override
public boolean match(final InetAddress addr)
{
    final byte[] bytes = addr.getAddress();
    int counter = 0;
    for(final ByteRule rule : this.rules)
    {
        if(counter + 1 == bytes.length) break; //In case there aren't enough bytes
        final int value = bytes[counter] < 0 ? (int) bytes[counter] + 256 : bytes[counter];
        if(!rule.match(value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a cleaner/more efficient solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: *Obviously the `this.rules.get(i)` on every iteration is inefficient* That is not obvious to me at all.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7401635/2268996) is how you can get rid of the ternary expression. Bitwise AND it with `0xFF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be happy with:

```
@Override
public boolean match(final InetAddress inetAddress)
{
    final byte[] bytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
    int end = Math.min(this.rules.size(), bytes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        final int adressPart = bytes[i] & 0xFF; //byte range from -128 to 127, &0xFF makes it unsigned, therefore positive
        if(!this.rules.get(i).match(adressPart))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you think, the `this.rules.get(i)`, then test it with a profiler. I would be surprised if this line is the reason for any slowdown, because the length of a InetAddress is probably quite limited and most likely implemented as an ArrayList annyway. If it really matters, you can change it to:

```
@Override
public boolean match(final InetAddress inetAddress)
{
    final byte[] bytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
    ByteRule[] byteRulesArray = rules.toArray(new String[rules.size()]);
    int end = Math.min(this.rules.size(), bytes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        final int adressPart = bytes[i] & 0xFF; //byte range from -128 to 127, &0xFF makes it unsigned, therefore positive
        if(!byteRulesArray[i].match(adressPart))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

or if you even fear the array creation, you can use an iterator:

```
@Override
public boolean match(final InetAddress inetAddress)
{
    final byte[] bytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
    Iterator<ByteRule> rulesIterator = rules.iterator();
    int end = Math.min(this.rules.size(), bytes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        final int adressPart = bytes[i] & 0xFF; //byte range from -128 to 127, &0xFF makes it unsigned, therefore positive
        if(!rulesIterator.next.match(adressPart))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hint: In theory, the iterator solution would be faster than the array creation. However in the real world, because of hardware reasons, the array creation will, most likely, be faster.

Comment: I love the third solution, thank you very much for your help.